# Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260: This device cannot start (code 10)

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, wifi-driver, wireless-adapter

My wireless driver seems to be down, and as a result my WiFi no longer works. I've tried disabling/enabling it from the device manager as well as shutting down and booting the system back up to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 does not do a full shutdown unless you explicitly tell it to or disable fast startup from the power management settings. I temporary solved the problem by executing `shutdown /s /t 0` from the command line and rebooting, but this doesn't prevent the wireless card/driver from eventually failing again. Something I'm still seeking a solution for.

Comment: easier way is to hold shift key while you click shutdown.

Comment: In Windows 98 when used with restart it did a fast restart (skip bios loading again) of the OS, a real time saver in the day.